# Differ in HTTP Get request result between POSTMAN & Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, google-chrome

Why does it happen? i tried to run the same get method request using postman, and google chrome browser, it gives me 2 different result. I've been using this method to get mysql data from an android app with json response i also have been trying to get the result the same as Google Chrome's result, but somehow my response it gives me is like the POSTMAN's result.

I ran this http request to both postman an google chrome, here's the request and the result.

This is from POSTMAN

```
::POSTMAN:: 
http://nfctracker.epizy.com/appFetchAccountType.php?username=admin&password=adminpass

::Result::

<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
        <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("28d28fe88f79072012ef637023c34a3a");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://nfctracker.epizy.com/appFetchAccountType.php?username=admin&password=adminpass&i=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is from Google Chrome

```
::Google Chrome::
http://nfctracker.epizy.com/appFetchAccountType.php?username=admin&password=adminpass

::Result::

{"result":[{"name":"admin","type":"1","company":"1"}]}
```

Can any of you help me solve this? i tries a lot of ways to deal with this, but still couldn't find the way out.

appFetchAccountType.php

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

require_once('appDbConnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$username."' and    password='".md5($password)."'";

$r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array(); 

if($res){
 array_push($result,array(
"name"=>$res['username'],
"type"=>$res['type'],
"company"=>$res['company']
)
);
}else{
array_push($result,array(
"name"=>$res['username'],
"type"=>$res['type'],
"company"=>$res['company']
)
);
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));    
mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Comment: maybe from postman, you are not sending data correctly

Comment: I tried a lot of times, but it still the same, this happened because i have change mysql php hosting services from '000webhost' to 'epizy' and i know that this is the exactly the correct ways of doing it.

Comment: I just discovered that this web hosting i'm using has a custom built bot protection system which helps to protect my website against content theft and hacking, but it does block automated tools which connect to my account as well. Unfortunately, this system cannot be disabled. thanks anyway for all your help.